# Why does this do what it does?

Tags: python, syntax

I found this interesting item in a blog today:

```
def abc():
    try:
        return True
    finally:
        return False

print "abc() is", abc()
```

Can anyone tell why it does what it does?

Thanks,
KR

Comment: Although not entirely the same, a good discussion of this can be found 
here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611561/python-error-handling-with-try-finally

Comment: -1: did not even try to look up the finally statement in http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

Answer (score 10):

If the finally block contains a `return` or `break` statement the result from the try
block is discarded

it's explained in detail in the [python docu](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the try statement area:

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html

The finally statement is still executed.  Really interesting situation though. I learned something new. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointer to the docs.  I could not get past the 'return True' to even think of looking there.

Part of the documentation reads:

> If finally is present, it specifies a
>   ‘cleanup’ handler. **The try clause is
>   executed,**...

which suggests that the return True is executed.  However, this is later clarified:

> When a return, break or continue
>   statement is executed in the try suite
>   of a try...finally statement, the
>   finally clause is also executed ‘on
>   the way out.’

Which explains the observed behavior.

What kind of mind would think up some code like this in the first place? ;)