# creepy design in python

Tags: python

can somebody help me with the following piece of the code:

```
try:
    #do some things
    myClass.close()
except Exception, error:
    myClass.close()
    raise error
```

as You see I can't use here `finally` because in that case I will not know if an error actually occured, and I need to raise this error (raise error)

my question is how can I avoid using this two times `myClass.close()?` thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please **never** re-raise exception in this way. **Always** use a plain `raise` for this purpose. Otherwise you lose the original backtrace which is pretty annoying in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to your code:

```
try:
    #do some things
finally:
    myClass.close()
```

First it calls `myClass.close()` and if there was a error it is raised again.

You can also have this to handle specific exceptions:

```
try:
    #do some things
except Exception, error:
    raise # re-raise the original exception
finally:
    myClass.close()
```

Comment: Use only `raise` to re-raise the exception instead of using `raise error` to keep the backtrace of the original exception.

Comment: What happens if the close itself raises an exception in the various cases (e.g. - an exception was already raised in the try block)?  Can / should you wrap the close inside the finally block in another try block that swallows any / all exceptions the close raises?  Will that preserve the previous exception raised in the original try block?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `finally` :)

This should do what you want:

```
try:
    #do some things
finally:
    myClass.close()
```

Comment: ok, but in that case, how will I receive an indication that an exception was raised?

Comment: @yeap: The exception will automatically be re-raised after the `finally` block finishes (if there was one).

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `try`, `except` and `finally` [since Python 2.5](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

```
try:
    # Do some things...
    pass
except Exception, error:
    # Log the error...
    raise
finally:
    myClass.close()
```

Comment: Use only `raise` instead of `raise error` to keep the backtrace of the original exception.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, you're absolutely right. Answer updated, thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 1):

Next to a finally (that would work) you could also use a context manager that calls your myClass.close() method on exit.

Answer (score 0):

Nest it.

```
try:
  try:
    ...
  except ...:
    raise error
finally:
  myClass.close()
```

Comment: Same thing here - use `raise` instead of `raise whatever` to re-raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless this will not work.
If you already raised an exception/error the first time you invoked myClass.close(), calling it again will be of no help.
The error handling keywords are for implementing fallbacks, reporting and routing of the error-flow.

See here for error handling:
[Can I get the exception from the finally block in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611561/python-error-handling-with-try-finally)