# Why finally-block is executed after a try-block containing return statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I'm wondering why the function *foo* is returning 3 instead 1. Please explain.

```
def foo():
    try:
        return 1
    except:
        return 2
    finally:
        return 3
```

Comment: Because that's exactly what `finally` is for - to *always* run.

Comment: Please search before posting:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805654/python-try-finally-block-returns

Comment: how does it make sense, when an explicit return statement is mentioned?

Comment: @nik_kgp have you *read* the duplicate? It explains what is happening.

Comment: I have surely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The finally block executes regardless of Exceptions. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611561/python-error-handling-with-try-finally).

To elaborate, the `finally` clause is always executed before the end of the `try` statement. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: But how does it skip the `return 1`?

Comment: In the mentioned try-block, no exception is being raised.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that the finally block executes before leaving the try statement. No idea why people have downvoted this, it's correct. And since there's a return statement in the finally block, the entire function exits. If there wasn't, it would go back to the try statement, try it and continue based on whether there was an exception or not.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense it's "paused" while the `finally` block runs (as it is guaranteed to always do), then because of the `return` in that block never gets "unpaused" (as the function is now over).

Answer (score 0):

Finally is always the last item to happen after executing a try block.

Yes, the finally block is executed however the flow leaves the try block - whether by reaching the end, returning, or throwing an exception.