# Elegant way of re-raise exception with finally part exists

Tags: python

I want to catch exception out of a function, while if `finally` part exists in the function, the outer part couldn't know exception exists.

Here is the code:

```
def f():
    l = []

    try:
        raise Exception('fake')
    except:
        raise e
    finally:
        return l

try:
    f()
except:
    print 'wrong'
else:
    print 'right'
```

Output is

```
right
```

And if I remove "finally" part, it will output wrong as expected.

I know the reason from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611561/can-i-get-the-exception-from-the-finally-block-in-python), but I don't know any elegant way to deal with this scenario, how should I write code if I need *re-raise* and `finally` together?

Comment: Other than not returning in `finally`?

Comment: thanks, so you mean "use return in finally part" is bad idea?

Comment: you do know that finally always gets executed right?

Comment: thanks for help guys, I think it's my wrong way of "finally" usage